# How to select columns based on the max value of each column?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with many columns and rows, for example

```
id  column1 column2 column3
1   2   3   5
2   3   2   6
3   4   1   3
4   1   1   2
5   3   3   2
6   5   2   1
```

How can I select the column (except id) whose max value is more than certain value, like 5 in the example data?

So the select data should be:

```
id  column1 column3
1   2   5
2   3   6
3   4   3
4   1   2
5   3   2
6   5   1
```

I would appreciate any help on my question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways to do this.

Using base R

```
cbind(df[1], df[-1][sapply(df[-1], function(x) any(x >=5))])

#  id column1 column3
#1  1       2       5
#2  2       3       6
#3  3       4       3
#4  4       1       2
#5  5       3       2
#6  6       5       1
```

We could also use `colSums` on logical matrix after comparing it with `>= 5`

```
cbind(df[1], df[-1][colSums(df[-1] >= 5)  > 0])
```

Or with `Filter`

```
cbind(df[1], Filter(function(x) any(x >= 5), df[-1]))
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

bind_cols(df[1], df %>%
                 select(-1) %>%
                 select_if(~any(. >=5)))
```

Answer (score 2):

That requires first finding those maximal values and then accordingly subsetting the data frame, as in

```
df[c(TRUE, apply(df[-1], 2, max) >= 5)]
#   id column1 column3
# 1  1       2       5
# 2  2       3       6
# 3  3       4       3
# 4  4       1       2
# 5  5       3       2
# 6  6       5       1
```

where

```
apply(df[-1], 2, max)
# column1 column2 column3 
#       5       3       6
```

and adding `TRUE` also preserves the `id` column.